# Order by nested document Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having multiple documents in a collection, each document has this data structure :

```
   {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "5429409c9ac25ebe338b4567"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "data_id": "70",
                    "info_data": [
                        {
                            "data_id": "98",
                            "data_index": 0,
                            "value": "info data"
                        },
                        {
                            "data_id": "99",
                            "data_index": 0,
                            "value": "some info data
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "data_id": "71",
                    "info_data": [
                        {
                            "data_id": "98",
                            "data_index": 0,
                            "value": "some data"
                        },
                        {
                            "data_id": "99",
                            "data_index": 0,
                            "value": "more data"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "542940ac9ac25ef6358b4567"
            },
            "data": [
                {
    ....
```

I need to conditionally sort these documents. for example I need to sort all the data.info_data documents only when the data.info_data.data_id = 98 by data.info_data.value only

So basically I need to sort an inner document that only matches to some criteria (the inner document no the external one).

I guess I need to use aggregation with unwind but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Can you edit your question to format your doc in JSON instead?

Comment: You got it, let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: To clear up possible confusion, could you show us what you want the output to be?